# ODE: Newtons Second Law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am solving past exam papers; ODE, and have trouble solving this problem

a) Suppose that a hole is now drilled directly from the surface of the Earth at the
North Pole, all the way through the centre to the surface at the South Pole.
A particle of mass m is dropped into this hole from a resting position at the
North Pole at time t = 0. Define r(t) as the displacement of the particle from
the centre of the Earth at time t. Using Newton’s Second Law, show that r(t)
satisfies the differential equation

$\frac{ d^
2
r}
{d t^2}
= −k^
2
r(t)$,                              (1)

where  $ k^
2$ = $\frac {GM}{R^
3} = g/R$, where g = 9.81ms^−2
is the gravitational
acceleration at the surface of the Earth

b)By solving equation (1), show that the particle undergoes periodic simple
harmonic motion with a period approximately equal to 84 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g=9.8m/s2 is at the surface of the Earth.

The acceleration would be progressively smaller as you approached the center.

And this changes your equation.

See:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/earthole.html